# Where can I find the history of job application

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have sent some application requests in stackoverflow JOB search section. Where can I find the history of my applications and the texts I wrote in the application forms? Currently I have to search the name of company again, then find the job position and then the only thing I can view is that I have applied there before... nothing more.

**Edit:** I received an Email from stackoverflow which have direct link to the application details. But I can not find the entrance of that page from JOB section itself rather than the Email link.

Answer (score 15):

Finally I found the secret way to view the Job application history:

1. Go to job section of stackoverflow.com
2. In desktop version, on to right of window, there is an envelope (message) icon besides of the gear(settings) icon. It is your inbox and all actions goes here!
3. In inbox section, change the filter to "`sent`" items and you can find your sent applications there.

**Footnote:** I am still trying to find another secret way to access this section in mobile version of stackoverflow.com.